# APFS Encrypted vs APFS + FileVault?

Tags: mojave, encryption, filevault, apfs

I upgraded the SSD in a Mac Mini and I'm reinstalling Mojave via internet recovery.

The disk is completely erased right now, and when creating a new partition it asks me if I want to choose `APFS` or `APFS (Encrypted)`.

I want full encryption on the drive. Should I go with `APFS` then enable FileVault later on, or simply partition the disk with `APFS (Encrypted)`?

Comment: I suspect there's no essential difference between the two. If you've selected the Encrypted format, it's possible that FV may show as on (what else is FV if not an encrypted file system?). If it doesn't, there's certainly no advantage to adding FV to an already encrypted format.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tested both options on my own: on Mojave installing on a new disk with  `APFS (Encrypted)` results in a fully working system with FileVault already enabled.

Comment: Isnt FIleVault always activated by default on a SSD Mac?

Comment: Just received new 2019 iMac with SSD only with Mojave and FileVault was not activated.

Comment: @Mick No, FileVault is never activated by default on any Mac.

Comment: @sw.smayer97 Brand new Macs with the T2 chip have built-in drive encryption, even though FileVault is shown as "off".